# LLVM creating executable code from C/C++ builder

Tags: c++, llvm, elf, llvm-codegen

I have get an example llvm code from [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-createcompilerllvm1/index.html). This code has some problems that I fixed them too. At this point, all it does is to dump the translated IR code. What I am after is to create an executable from my `C++` code without calling `llvm-as`/`llc`/`clang` in my bash. How can I achieve that?

I do not want to create any IR or bytecode intermediate file at all too.

```
#include <llvm/ADT/ArrayRef.h>
#include <llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Function.h>
#include <llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h>
#include <llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    llvm::LLVMContext context;
    llvm::Module *module = new llvm::Module("myModule", context);
    llvm::IRBuilder<> builder(context);

    llvm::FunctionType *funcType = llvm::FunctionType::get(builder.getVoidTy(), false);
    llvm::Function *mainFunc = 
        llvm::Function::Create(funcType, llvm::Function::ExternalLinkage, "main", module);
    llvm::BasicBlock *entry = llvm::BasicBlock::Create(context, "entrypoint", mainFunc);
    builder.SetInsertPoint(entry);

    llvm::Value *helloWorld = builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr("hello world!\n");

    std::vector<llvm::Type *> putsArgs;
    putsArgs.push_back(builder.getInt8Ty()->getPointerTo());
    llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Type*>  argsRef(putsArgs);

    llvm::FunctionType *putsType = 
        llvm::FunctionType::get(builder.getInt32Ty(), argsRef, false);
    llvm::FunctionCallee putsFunc = module->getOrInsertFunction("puts", putsType);

    builder.CreateCall(putsFunc, helloWorld);
    builder.CreateRetVoid();
    module->print(llvm::errs(), nullptr);
}
```

A side question: BTW, when I am searching for LLVM examples, a lot of results are IR examples. How can I get the results to teach creating from C++?

Comment: Have you looked at the `JITEngine`? checkout llvm's kaleidoscope tutorial. The tutorial you're onto is outdated.

Comment: @droptop, at [Kaleidoscope](https://github.com/keyboardio/Kaleidoscope), I cannot spot it. Can you please help me finding the point?

Comment: @ar2015 https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/BuildingAJIT1.html

Comment: @droptop , I don't feel comfortable about llvm documentation. It looks like they are reluctant to write a proper tutorial: `Example code from Chapters 3 to 5 will compile and run, but has not been updated`. I also do not look after JIT. I want a natural compilation.

Comment: @droptop, just now someone told me that I cannot do this. I need to dump it to an object file first then creating an executable out of it. Is this true?

Comment: @ar2015 Yup. There's no escaping object files if you want to create an executable. You however just interpret your generated IR using `lli`, which of course doesn't create an executable.